# Fastapi. Pydantic не может сериализовать поле отвечающее за отношение один ко многим

Tags: python, сериализация, fastapi, pydantic

Тренируюсь делать мини блок. Столкнулся с проблемой что при команде  uvicorn main:app --reload
по началу всё хорошо, сервер загружается, но когда я пытаюсь зайти в http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs возникает ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Tracert сообщений слишком много  , не стал скидывать все, концовка вот такая
raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: parent

Но то что я из них понял, что в моих 2 моделях есть поля отношений relationship , в них     comments : List['Comment'] = relationship("Comment", back_populates="post") который не может pydantic сериализовать. Как исправить эту ошибку

Вот код

```
from typing import List

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from pydantic import BaseModel


DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:leopard@localhost/blog"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

#Base = declarative_base()


class Post(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id : int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title : str = Column(String, index=True)
    content : str = Column(String)
    # Определяем отношение "один ко многим" с моделью Comment
    comments : List['Comment'] = relationship("Comment", back_populates="post")


class Comment(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    content: str = Column(String)
    post_id:int = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    post :'Post' = relationship("Post", back_populates="comments")


app = FastAPI()

# Функция для получения объекта сессии базы данных


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

# Этот эндпоинт возвращает список всех постов в блоге
# - skip: int - количество постов, которые нужно пропустить (по умолчанию 0)
# - limit: int - максимальное количество постов для возврата (по умолчанию 100)
# - db: Session - объект сессии базы данных


@app.get("/posts", response_model=List[Post])
def read_posts(skip: int = 0, limit=100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    # Выполнение запроса к базе данных для получения списка постов с учетом пропуска и лимита
    posts = db.query(Post).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
    # Возвращаем список постов в качестве ответа на запрос
    return posts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так дело в том что твои модели наследуются от `pydantic.BaseModel`
Тебе нужно расскомментировать `#Base = declarative_base()` и сделать модели наследниками этого класса `Base`

Далее нужно создать уже схемы моделей, это делается так:

```py
class PostSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    comments: List['CommentSchema']


class CommentSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    content: str
```

Вот уже такие схемы могут быть валидированы fastapi.

Поэтому твою функцию (endpoint) `read_posts` нужно изменить вот так:

```py
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.get("/posts")
def read_posts(skip: int = 0, limit=100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):    
    posts = db.query(Post).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
    posts_schema = []
    for post in posts:
        comments_schema = []
        for comment in post.comments:
            comment_schema = CommentSchema(
                 id=comment.id,
                 content=comment.content,
            )
            comments_schema.append(comment_schema)
        post_schema = PostSchema(
            id=post.id,
            title=post.title
            content=post.content,
            comments=comments_schema
        )
        posts_schema.append(post_schema.model_dump()) # Преобразовываем объект в json
    return JSONResponse(posts_schema)
```

Теперь в переменной `posts_schema` хранится `json` (а не объекты класса), который `fastapi` может отправить.

P.S. Так же можно в классы моделей `SQLAlchemy` добавить метод который бы преобразовывал объекты класса моделей `SQLAlchemy` в модели `pydantic.BaseModel`
Например это можно сделать так:

```py
class Comment(BaseM):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    content: str = Column(String)
    post_id:int = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    post :'Post' = relationship("Post", back_populates="comments")

    def to_schema(self) -> CommentSchema:
        return CommentSchema(
            id=self.id,
            content=self.content
        )
```

Это позволит тебе в любом месте преобразовать твои данные в `json`

```py
comment.to_schema().model_dump()
```

P.S. [Пример как связать SQLAlchemy и Pydantic можно посмотреть тут](https://github.com/artemonsh/fastapi-onion-architecture/tree/pt1_onion_arc/src)